# How to stream data over WiFi on Android without creating multiple AsyncTasks?

Tags: android, networking

I need to stream the accelerometer positions from my cellphone to my computer, and I'm doing something like this, for every new accelerometer position.

```
AsyncTask<String, Void, String> task = new SendUDPTask();
task.execute("192.168.0.101", x + " " + y + " " + z);
```

Inside the AsyncTask, I'm sending the data via UDP.

I know that you can't execute an AsyncTask more than one time, and I know that creating a new object every time I am sending a position (about 30 positions/second) is probably not the right way.

What is the most optimal way to do that without creating a new AsyncTask object for every new accelerometer position?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you do with sent the positions.

If you want something close to real-time, you have no choice but to send as soon as you receive an accelerometer event.

If real-time does not matter (or doesn't have to be that "real") you can wait until you receive N positions (e.g. 30) and send them all at once. Remember that you set the accelerometer refresh rate for the listener.

Comment: Is creating an AsyncTask for every new accelerometer event the right way, though?

Comment: As I said it depends on what you want to acheive. Is timing important?